# Polynomial coefficients for $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n - 1}\frac{N-i}{N}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

Given,

$$
\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n - 1}\frac{N-i}{N},
$$

such that $n \leq N$, I know the first two terms of the expansion are

$$
1 - \frac{{n \choose 2}}{N}.
$$

What is the general formula for the polynomial coefficient for the $i$th term?

Comment: Check the Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Looks like I have some reading to do -- thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: What is $N?$ Or is $N=n?$

Comment: N is arbitrary, such that $n \leq N$.